# CRON & CLI for basic Magento inventory update automation?

Tags: php, magento, cron, command-line-interface

I'm new to cli and cron so need some mentoring/guidance.

I have a Magento store that will at some time in the near future have a direct API to Sage 200.

Until then I need to automate stock inventory updates.

I use Magmi for nearly all imports, but am struggling to find a clear instruction for setting up a scheduled (daily) import of a cvs containing the SKU, Qty & Price fields.

I really don't have the time to learn all the code myself at the moment, (although its on my list), so am looking for some guidance on how to set up Magmi to import via CLI and create a CRON to run daily.

We have a tool that spits out cvs or xml files from Sage 200 and can put them in a folder on the server.  its JUST the bit that picks the file up and imports once a day!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your CSV file created and ready to go you just need to set your Magmi profile up and then you can call it (on a cron) like this:

```
php /path/to/your/website/httpdocs/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php -profile=<the magmi profile you want to use> -mode=create -CSV:filename="/path/to/your/csv/file.csv"
```

Comment: where do I set the cron?  In CPanel?  or via ssh?

Comment: Either... but if you're not used to cron I would set it in cPanel

Comment: Thanks.  So I just found that the csv that Sage spits out has different name each time as it adds a date stamp.  Can I config the cron to pick up newest file in the folder?

Comment: I think you will need to have a think about this then...as I guess the format that sage spits out will be different to what magmi requires. You could have a cron that runs first that gets the latest file and gives it a standard name (e.g. sageimport.csv) then pass this as a parameter to magmi call. That might be a subject for a different SO question though...

Comment: Thanks, so in the /path/to/your/website/httpdocs/magmi, etc does the path require full as in '/root/home/public_html/dev/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php' or just '/public_html/dev/magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php'? and which for the cvs file?

Comment: Both paths require the full server path